# Python - getting statistics without creating variable/dataframe from input file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of .txt files, which together form a dataframe that is too much to get loaded into a variable (ergo there's not enough memory to load all the files into a pandas dataframe). Can I somehow get some descriptive statistics by just reading the files but not loading them into a dataframe/variable? How? Thank you!

Comment: You can iterate over the files and append the result of `df.describe()` for each file. That way you wouldn't need to load each file and keep them in memory

Comment: Use [online statistical algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1058813/190597).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get information, you can select the files with glob, open them as text files. 
Assuming this is a CSV file with column titles on the first line, you can retrieves the keys by splitting the first line.
Based on [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python), count the remaining lines.

```
import glob    

filenames = glob.glob('*.txt')
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as f:
        keys = f.readline().rstrip().split(',')
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    print("File:", filename, " keys:", keys," len:",i+1)
```