# How to efficiently calculate skew and kurtosis given new numbers without having to store full list of numbers

Tags: python, statistics

I want to calculate mean / std / skew / kurtosis on a incremental basis without having to store previous numbers. What is the most stable and efficient way of doing so?

For example for mean, I can take: [image]

This post gives a way to do the same for standard deviation and variance. [How to efficiently calculate a running standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174984/how-to-efficiently-calculate-a-running-standard-deviation)

But what about skew and kurtosis?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059163/765091