# Selection Algorithm to Find Median

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, selection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate or approximate the median of a list without storing the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638030/how-to-calculate-or-approximate-the-median-of-a-list-without-storing-the-list)

I want to apply using C# an algorithm to find the median value using selection/quick sort. But I do not want to sort the whole array in order to get the median.

Can I do it?

Comment: Why would you NOT WANT to sort the whole array? I think it is mandatory to sort the whole array as it is the keypoint for finding the exact median (not guess the probable median)..

Comment: The posted link isn't [tag:C#] specifically, however the algorithm could easily be applied.

Comment: @ Abbas sorting the whole array is very expensive!!

Comment: @George the link does not seem to be working it link to the whole C# tag!!

Comment: I was refering to my "possible duplicate" comment.

Comment: You do not have to sort the whole array. Each time you have to sort only half of the array.

Comment: The supposed duplicate question link is for approximate, not exact median. Not sure how that blunder slipped in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia's entry on [Selection Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) gives various alternatives, including the *Median of Medians* approach, which would seem to fit your requirements. In particular, it has a worst-case performance of O(n).