# Find the Median of 10 numbers(unsorted)?

Tags: c, median

I cant Use ARRAY.
I have to use only one variable.
And calculate the median.
i use following code to enter 10 nos(Unsorted)

```
Printf("enter 10 nos");
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
scanf("%d",&a);
```

I tried but can only find the minimum and maximum.but no luck with middle most no.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate or approximate the median of a list without storing the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638030/how-to-calculate-or-approximate-the-median-of-a-list-without-storing-the-list)

Comment: Live on Earth without breathing!!

Comment: i cant use any thing like list ,array,stack  just 1 variable for 10 nos...so retaining it is a great problem

Comment: The restriction on having only a single variable is not practical. Use as many variables as you want. That's what they're for. And since the array is so small, you may as well sort it. (Besides, your code above uses two variables already, so the one variable restriction is already being ignored.)

Comment: i want to use many variable but my TEACHER said it has a possible solution using a single variable

Comment: @user2873941 do you mean three variables? loop counter, input from user and accumulator...

Comment: @user2873941. may be your teacher looks for a mathematic demonstration that kind of operation is impossible

Comment: Would you post the solution you came up with for the "minimum" problem. I would like to clearly understand what really are your restrictions

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't understand your teacher when she said "single variable"...

Comment: i have to use a single variable to store the input but i can use other variable for running the loop,storing minimum and maximum and other counter variable

Comment: "median" means `sum/count`?  As `count` is 10 in your problem, you need only a variable for `sum` which is updated in your loop (`sum += a`).

Comment: @ensc That's mean, not median.

Comment: @Jekyll That's a good point. I hadn't thought of that...

Comment: Are sure your teacher is asking for the *median* and not the *mean*?

Comment: YES she asked for median.

Comment: Let me say you are at the second number and you have 4 and 6, there is only one variable to store the value. Which will you store there? That's a real problem, because the other variable will be lost and if that was the median now it's gone, you won't remember you had a 4.

Comment: i will store 4 in min..min=4 and 6 in max..max=4

Comment: i cant use different variables to store different numbers as the user enters

Comment: You can't use an array... Can you use a linked list or a heap?

Comment: You can't compute a median without storing at least half of the values... You misunderstood.

Comment: The median of _10_ numbers cannot, in general, be expected to be 1 of the 10 numbers.  It needs to be the "number" between the 5th and 6th number.  Therefore _some_ calculation on the numbers needs to be had.  Note: adding bot INT_MIN and INT_MAX to the list does not change the answer - not sure if this helps.  BTW: What is the range of allowable numbers to enter?

Comment: @chux any 10 numbers i.e. integer type

Comment: possible duplicate of [C program to find the median of of 10 numbers without using array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245540/c-program-to-find-the-median-of-of-10-numbers-without-using-array)

Comment: BTW: `for(i=0;i<=10;i++)` iterates 11 times.  Suggest `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)`.

Comment: Don't forget to share the answer with us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the median of an unsorted array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662013/finding-the-median-of-an-unsorted-array)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy since to do it on one traversal without prior sorting but it can be done.

You need a way of calculating the *running median*.

One approach is to use an **order statistic tree**. See http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/OrderStatisticsTree. That's probably the *single variable* that your teacher is talking about. But it's not easy to coerce into a single variable in C.

But it's not a sensible way of getting the median statistic. The normal route is to build an interpolator representing a quantile function and use that to extract the median.

Comment: The order statistic tree can be used if the inputs are random. That's the whole point. Did you read the link?