# Finding a median dynamically without saving observations in C++ for O(n)

Tags: c++, algorithm, median

I launch the app and start retrieving some value from a sensor every `50 milliseconds`, I get some float value from [-1;1] range. How would I calculate the median value of all values I got from sensor since the launch of the app without storing them into any vector/array at all?

I understand that I can put values into a sorted collection and find the middle element or the sum of two middle elements divided by `2`. I also checked [`std::nth_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) which doesn't even require sorting, however, I would want to avoid storing these numbers in a heap, stack or hard drive. The app can keep working for hours so the amount of number accumulated by the sensor will be massive.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need the median ? average doesn't need storage for example.

Comment: Have you already tried those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638030/how-to-calculate-or-approximate-the-median-of-a-list-without-storing-the-list ?

Comment: If your data points are floating-point, the best you can do to save memory is to cast them to integers and store these to calculate the median later on. The set of real numbers is bigger than the set of integers, so, hopefully, you'll need to store less individual integers that way. It'll decrease precision, though.

Comment: What is **range** of your data?

Comment: @Jarod42 Unfortunately, I need median.

Comment: @MBo The range is [-1;1] float

Comment: @Ross Stepaniak What about `I get some integer value` ?

Comment: @MBo Sorry, I corrected the question. The range is always between -1.0f and 1.0f

Comment: OK. Usually sensor response has limited set of values (for example, internal 10-bit ADC produces only 1024 possible float results), so precision compromiss in my answer might be reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

For values in limited range you can use histogram approach to diminish storage space

Create array of counters and at every step increment counter corresponding to current value.

Example for 16-bit integer values:

```
int H[65536];
...
H[Value]++;
```

For float values (linear mapping with some loss of precision):

```
intIndex = (int) (65535 * (Value - RangeMin) / (RangeMax - RangeMin));
H[intIndex]++;
```

When needed, sum `H` entries until `Count/2` is reached.

If median is required at every step, keep median index, sums in the left and right part of histogram, update these sums, shift median index when `LeftSum + H[median]` becomes smaller than `RightSum` and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the values stored in a `std::vector` (`v`), the simplest solution I can think of would be

```
std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size()/2, v.end());
std::cout << "The median is " << v[v.size()/2] << '\n';
```

*I* don't know of any way to calculate the median without storing the intermediate values.

Answer (score -4):

There is no way to find an exact median without storing the values. It's possible for average, but not for medians.

Comment: Can you give a hint for the proof that it is not possible? Or is it just an assumption of yours?

Comment: I think it's a fairly safe assumption, given that the standard algorithm for this problem seems to be quickselect. If there was a more memory-efficient algorithm for this purpose, it would be known, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Your reasoning could be applied to **all** known algorithms, implying that we already know everything there is to know about computer science and no more research is needed...

Comment: I have to disagree. Trying to apply that reasoning to everything would be foolish, but the assumption that simple, widely used algorithms have been looked into multiple times by intelligent people is a relatively safe one. For example, you can keep looking for a new integer division algorithm, but it's highly unlikely that you'll find anything more efficient than what has already been found.