# Table Design for Calculating Median Over User-Defined Period from Pre-Processed Data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-design, entity-framework-core

I’m working with a table that contains pre-processed data from several other tables. This data is segmented by a time period (like a day) to speed up queries that could take minutes if I had to process everything each time a user wants to see a summary of that day or multiple days. Most fields are “simple” accumulations of calculated data, such as the accumulated timespans of multiple events.

Now, I need to present the median value of these events over a user-defined time period. The time periods are sets of multiple rows from my pre-processed data. I can calculate the median for the specific day that was pre-processed, but if the user needs the median from various days, I need the original calculated values. My current approach is to store it in an array of the values to be able to use them when needed.

I can’t simply go over the original tables and recalculate the timespans for the period, as the original table of this specific data has many rows and the timespans need to be calculated with a specific set of rules (this is one of the reasons to have it pre-processed in the first place).

Creating a new table to store these values seems counterproductive, as I would now have multiple rows of seemingly “duplicated” data just so I can get the median.

I understand that it’s a bad practice to use one field to store multiple values and wouldn’t advocate for it, but in this particular case, all the options seem to return worse results. Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: can you provide your source code?

Comment: I am going to assume you really do mean *median* and not *average*. My initial gut feeling is that I don't think there is a good way to partition and then pre-process the partitioned data in a way that would feed a median calculation of the combined data. Any value of any partition might be the median value when combined with adjacent partitions, which limits the ability to reduce data.  About the best you could do would be to group-by and count duplicate values within each partition, but that would only be useful if you had a high degree of value duplication.

Comment: Short answer is that you're smoked. But maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638030/how-to-calculate-or-approximate-the-median-of-a-list-without-storing-the-list can be of interest

Comment: Perhaps storing some sort of histogram per day can be good enough

Comment: @TN Yes, I do mean the median. I’m aware of certain shortcuts that can be used when dealing with medians, but they are applicable only in really specific scenarios. This is the reason why I find it necessary to store the set of timespans for each "day". Consequently, when I need to compute the median for a week or any other timeframe, for instance, I can avoid the time-consuming process of sifting through all the original data and calculating it again.

Comment: @siggemannen That's some interesting approaches, thank you. But I need the exact values. The histogram too, it's insightful, but my data have considerable variation and I don't think it would work while mashing various datasets.

Comment: I think the practical answer may be to only pre-calculate the median (and other statistics like count, min, max, average) for common predefined periods like shifts, days, weeks, months, or years. For custom time-periods, you can calculate and present other composite statistics fairly easily, but not median, which you could present as "unavailable". Perhaps you could add a button to request a median calculation, if the user really needs it for the custom time-period. That costly calculation could then be scheduled for execution when resource usage is low, and made available for later retrieval.